# Practical advice for identifying important interactions terms (with glinternet, or other approaches)

Tags: r, regression, glmnet

I work with scientists who supply experimental data (often that doesn't come from deliberate Design of Experiments).  I am comfortable addressing the question of "which predictor variables are the most important?" through a combination of domain knowledge and regularized regression like Lasso.

Sometimes they'd like to explore the possibility of interactions between the predictor variables.  It's a reasonable question to ask, but more difficult to address.

I have experimented with `glinternet`, a package that uses regularized regression to select important interactions.  It often produces smaller prediction errors than `glmnet`, suggesting that some of the interaction effects it selects are important.  However, I am not confident in the results.  From my education in Design of Experiments, I learned that one must make very deliberate decisions to avoid biasing between the interaction terms.  Surely the interaction terms that `glinternet` identifies are biased with other interaction terms, or even some of the main effects.

It's possible for even main effects to be biased, so this concern exists even for the main effects.  However the interaction terms cause me a lot more angst because the possibility of biasing is much higher, and it's more difficult to leverage domain knowledge - the domain experts are less likely to have intuition about the interaction effects.

Is there any possibility for the automatic variable selection of interaction terms to be robust or interpretable?  Many thanks.

Comment: Did you mean "aliasing" instead of "biasing" ?

Comment: Yes, I mean aliasing.  Sorry for the confusion.